# Drag and drop not working on scaling

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, html5-draggable

My Application has the Drag and drop. But on scaling the window drag and drop not working properly. Here is the code.

```
<div class="scaled">
    <div class="draggable" id="draggable"></div>
    <div class="droppable" id="droppable"></div>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.draggable {
    height: 50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.droppable {
    height: 50px;
    width:50px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.scaled {
     -ms-transform: scale(0.5,0.5); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5,0.5); /* Safari */
    transform: scale(0.5,0.5);   
}
```

Jquery code

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        alert()
    }
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wuncnqsh/1/)

Comment: check out this page: https://gungfoo.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/jquery-ui-resizabledraggable-with-transform-scale-set/

Comment: this doesn't help me much...

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the position of the drag-n-drop in the drag event.

Code based on [Drag n Drop not working proper on scaling the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589332/drag-n-drop-not-working-proper-on-scaling-the-container)

```
var zoomScale = 0.5
$(".draggable").draggable({
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    var changeLeft = ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left; // find change in left
    var newLeft = ui.originalPosition.left + changeLeft / zoomScale; // adjust new left by our zoomScale

    var changeTop = ui.position.top - ui.originalPosition.top; // find change in top
    var newTop = ui.originalPosition.top + changeTop / zoomScale; // adjust new top by our zoomScale

    ui.position.left = newLeft;
    ui.position.top = newTop;
  }
});
```